# rx.js testing object equality by structure

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

I have an observable that emits JS objects, and I'd like in my tests to assert that the observable transformations I make will produce the correct JS objects. The problem is that I don't understand what kind of assertions rx.js is using because tests that should fail, are passing.

For example, I'd like this test, [based on one from the examples directory](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/testing/qunit/tests.js#L17-L33), to fail, but it doesn't. Notice that the produced value is `{ prop: 42 }` and the one expected is `{ prop: 43 }`.

```
test('returnValue Basic', function () {
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var results = scheduler.startWithCreate(function () {
        return Observable.returnValue({ prop: 42 }, scheduler);
    });

    var expectedMessages = [
        onNext(201, { prop: 43 }),
        onCompleted(201)
    ];

    CollectionAssert.assertEqual(expectedMessages, results.messages);
});
```

Does anyone know what's the problem, and how can I workaround it? I understand object equality in JavaScript, but that's the next step. It's obvious from the above test that rx.js isn't using either reference equality, nor structural equality.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in your console for errors?  JS test frameworks usually die in the face of test code that is accessing properties on `undefined`.

Without seeing your entire JS file I can only guess you've not defined your global variables: `TestScheduler`, `Observable`, `CollectionAssert`,`onNext`,`onCompleted`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I've gathered some more info, as you can see right here: https://gist.github.com/mattpodwysocki/6114182. In short, It's a bug combined with a... missing feature. BTW, the snippet in my question is thise one: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/testing/qunit/tests.js#L17-L33. The only thing I've modified is the emitted value.